# Guess Variables

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm making a card game and I dont know how to make the first card guess separate from the second card guess. I've looked at some examples on different codepens, but the code is kind of hard to understand. This is what I have so far..

UPDATE:

```
var cards = [
"flower", "happy", "moon",
"rocket", "taco", "tree"
];

var card1 = "";
var card2 = ""

$('div.inner').each(function() {
 $(this).find('button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    card1 = $(this).val();
    card2 = $(this).val();
 console.log(card1);
    console.log(card2);
  console.log("click = " + $(this).val());
 });
});
```

Here is what most of my html page looks like but with the different names of the card. The full thing is pretty long.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="flip">
            <div class="cards"> 
                <div class="face front">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <button class="btn flower" value="flower"><img src="imgs/card-front.jpg"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="face back">
                    <img src="imgs/flower.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just remove the guess from the array once it has been guessed. I didn't down-vote by the way.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here.  This doesn't "guess" anything, it just attaches a bunch of click handlers to buttons which print their own values to the console twice.  What is the *intended* functionality?

Comment: I dont really know how to really explain it. Basically I want two separate click functions for each flip of a card. My current code logs the same thing for card1 and card2, but I want them to be two separate guesses. I think i can figure out if it is a match or not, but I need to be able to run two different guess clicks to determine if the two cards or a match or not

Comment: My current code just gets the value of the clicked card, but now I need to make them two different guesses and thats where I'm stuck at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the final example how to add rules cars matches from shuffle odd cards using number, but you add your own rules of printing a did a little final end the cards fadeout after the select the good odds... etc

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var MYAPP = MYAPP || {
   cards: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
   init: function(){
      MYAPP.shuffleCards();
   },
   shuffleCards: function(){
     var random = 0;
     var temp = 0;
     for(i=0; i< MYAPP.cards.length; i++) {
        random = Math.round(Math.random()*i);               
        temp = MYAPP.cards[i]; 
        MYAPP.cards[i] = MYAPP.cards[random];
        MYAPP.cards[random] = temp;
        
     }     
     MYAPP.assignCards();
   },
    assignCards: function(){
      $('.card').each(function(index){
        $(this).attr('data-card-value', MYAPP.cards[index] );
      });
      MYAPP.clickHandlers();
    },
    clickHandlers: function(){
      $('.card').on('click', function(){
        $(this).html('<p>' + $(this).data('cardValue') + '</p>').addClass('selected');
        MYAPP.checkMatch();
      });
      
      $('.playAgain').on('click', function(){
        location.reload(true);
      });
    },
    checkMatch: function(){
      if($('.selected').length === 2) {
        if($('.selected').first().data('cardValue') === $('.selected').last().data('cardValue')) {
          $('.selected').each(function(){
            $(this).animate({opacity: 0}).removeClass('unmatched').removeClass('selected');
          });
          MYAPP.checkWin();
        } else {
          setTimeout(function(){
               $('.selected').each(function(){            
               $(this).html('').removeClass('selected');
             }); 
            },600);   
        }
      } 
    },
    checkWin: function(){
      if($('.unmatched').length === 0) {
        $('.container').html('<h1>YOU WON!</h1><button class="playAgain">PLAY AGAIN<?button>');
        MYAPP.clickHandlers();
      }
    }
  }
  
  MYAPP.init();
  
});
```

```css
html, body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;  
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 100 %;
  height:auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.cards {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  margin: 50px auto;  
}
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;  
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #3b3420;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 
    inset 4px 4px 8px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card p{
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
}
.container h1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 200px;
}
.container button{
  background-color: #f2c791;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #a67841;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;  
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="cards">
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hmm this is very interesting. I so i would just replace my forEach loop with something like this?

Comment: I edited the post with my html. Its not the full thing, but its what most of it looks like, except there is a different class for each type of card it is.

Comment: @JoeEscobedo ok i take a look.

Comment: that works great! My only issue now is getting two cards to match. I'm trying out a few things, an if statement makes it an automatic match when any card is picked.

Comment: I noticed that $(this).val() gives me the value of the card, but for some reason i cant make an if statement with it. It will make it a match as soon as one card is clicked.

Comment: add a `event.preventDefault();` at the begining of the click event, event taken from the default param of the function called. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I updated my javascript if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157844/discussion-between-headmax-and-joe-escobedo).